# private folder in github

Tags: svn, git, version-control, github, bazaar

```
/source/application/controller ( visible )
/source/application/models ( visible )
/source/application/views ( visible )
/source/framework ( not visible )
```

can we somehow do like this at github or in any git sites ? svn ? or maybe other SCM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using Git by using the [submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) support. You could create a repository for "application", and make that public. Then create a repository containing that, and set up "application" as a submodule. If you don't make the outer repository public, then it's effectively private.

Comment: I recommend reading the chapter in the Git book that I linked to in my answer. Setting up a submodule isn't just one command, you have to do a few things to make it all work. The Submodule chapter goes into a lot of detail. There's even a screencast at the end if that helps.